# matplotlib 3d scatter plot date

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a list of dates in format `15/10/2017`

I have tried the following

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas as pd

dates = ['15/10/2016', '16/10/2016', "17/10/2015", "15/10/2014"]
dates_formatted = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in dates ]
x = [1,2,3,4]
z = [5,6,7,8]

pyplot.scatter(x, dates_formatted, z)
pyplot.show()
```

It throws an error `TypeError: ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

It shows if it is 2D. e.g. `pyplot.scatter(x, dates_formatted)`

I have also tried the following

```
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, dates_formatted, y)
pyplot.show()
```

It throws an error `Float() argument must be a string or number`

Comment: I suspect you're actually calling the scatter method of the regular `Axes` object. Try creating a `Axes3d` object with `ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')` then doing what you've done.

Comment: Have tried it and updated the question

Answer (score 9):

It's not always trivial to tell `matplotlib` how to translate strings into a coordinate system. Why not simply set custom tick labels for the axes?

```
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure('scatter dates')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
dates = ['15/10/2016', '16/10/2016', "17/10/2015", "15/10/2014"]
dates_formatted = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in dates ]
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [9,10,11,12]
z = [5,6,7,8]

ax.scatter(x, y, z)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(x)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(dates_formatted)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So if I understand the solution correctly, the list of values on `x` are just arbitrary number such that we conform to the supported value for the `scatter()` function. Thereafter we just need to set a custom label(date) for the `x` axes to sort of 'replace' the values.

Comment: @MaTaKazer pretty much so, yes. In principle, you can calculate x values directly from a time string too, which would be a more meaningful way doing it.

Answer (score 4):

Scatter expects a number. So you can convert your dates to as number as follows:

```
y = [ (d-min(dates_formatted)).days for d in dates_formatted]
```

Now you can plot the data as

```
pyplot.scatter(x, y)
```

For a 3D plot, you can try something like this ...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

plt.ion()
x = [1,2,3,4]
z = [5,6,7,8]
dates = ['15/10/2016', '16/10/2016', "17/10/2015", "15/10/2014"]
dates_formatted = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in dates]

y = [ (d-min(dates_formatted)).days for d in dates_formatted]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
plt.scatter(x, y, z)
```

The y axis in now in days. You can change that by finding the date string, and changing it back ...

```
dt = [ pd.Timedelta(d) + min(dates_formatted)  for d in  ax.get_yticks()]
```

Convert these into strings ...

```
dtStr = [d.isoformat() for d in dt]
```

And put them back

```
ax.set_yticklabels(dtStr)
```